# Message box disappears when using a relay command

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, command

I have a RelayCommand class:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Func<bool> canExecuteEvaluator;

    private readonly Action methodToExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action methodToExecute, Func<bool> canExecuteEvaluator)
    {
        this.methodToExecute = methodToExecute;
        this.canExecuteEvaluator = canExecuteEvaluator;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action methodToExecute)
        : this(methodToExecute, null)
    {
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (this.canExecuteEvaluator == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            bool result = this.canExecuteEvaluator.Invoke();
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.methodToExecute.Invoke();
    }
```

In my view model I create my commands like this:

```
public RelayCommand CmdUpdate { get; private set; }

CmdUpdate = new RelayCommand(() => Updater.CheckForUpdate());
```

Updater.CheckForUpdate() simply checks if there is an update available and shows an message box.

I then bind the command to a menu item in my view.

When I press the item, the message box pops up for a split second and disappears again. Where is the propblem. An explanation is highly appreciated, so I can understand it.

Comment: How can we explain your code you did not show us?

Comment: Hey, thank you. It is just a simple message box. I have the same problem if I do the following: CmdUpdate = new RelayCommand(() => MessageBox.Show("Test")); The problem has to be somweher in the posted code.